# Does Object.assign output differ if a function is passed as the 'target' param

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, that executes successfully, but I am not quite sure how can this happen.

```js
var obj = Object.assign(
  (...args) => ({
    a: 1
  }),
  { toString: () => 'type' }
);
console.log(obj); // f type
```

Why is the output of the above not

```
{ 
  f: () => {
    return {a: 1}
  }, 
  toString: () => 'type'
}
```

Could someone give a detailed explanation of the above?

Comment: Where would the property `f` come from? Note that any `f` you see in the browser console indicates that the value *is* a function, not that the value has a property named `f`, in this case.

Comment: Functions are objects. You can assign properties to functions. When logging, the `toString` method of an object is used. – Unclear what the confusion is or why you'd expect what you expect.

Comment: `console.log` will call `toString`, use `console.dir` or inspect the object some other way.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.assign` copies the values of all the *enumerable own* properties of several source objects to a target object:

```js
Object.assign({ a: 'foo' }, { b: 'bar' });
// => { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }
```

In your given example the target object is the arrow function. In Javascript, functions are just objects (with their own enumerable properties) and you can add additional properties without worry.

The source object in your example is an object containing a property `toString` with a function value. You're essentially copying this property onto the destination function.

When you `console.log` the resulting object, `toString` is automatically called and its result is logged to the console. Since the object is actually a function you will see the *weird* output of `f type`. How this is shown is browser dependent though.

To answer your question as to why the returned object doesn't look like what you wrote: You extended the function itself. If you instead created a new object with property `f` to the given function you would get the desired result:

```js
const obj = Object.assign({
  f: (...args) => ({
    a: 1
})}, {
  toString: () => 'type'
});
  
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Does the automatic calling of the `toString` method, assign the name to the function?

PS: the `name` property is still an empty string, if I do `console.dir(obj)`

Comment: Nope, as you can might see the `f` in your console is slightly stylized as an italic f. This is purely the browser telling you that the value is a **f**unction, it's nothing Javascript does

Comment: I know and I agree, that the italicized `f` is an indication of a function, but the chrome browser displays the above in the same way, it would when using `console.log` on any other function declaration, without the function definition part. So is the appearance of the italicized `f`, browser specific?

Comment: I tested it on Safari, and the `f` doesn't appear in the console. So I believe this is just browser specific